# StartIntent for Browser crashes in Samsung running Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-intent

Following Java code crashes in Samsung Galaxy with Android 7.0 but works fine in Android 7.0 Simulator and also works fine in Motorola Moto G (3rd edition) with Android 6.0. I do not possess a Samsung device with Android 7.0, so can't debug. Any idea what could be wrong? The urlString is properly formatted, like https://www.google.com.

```
String urlString = event.getUrl().toString();
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlString));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Update: Also tested with a Samsung Note running Android 6.0 in Samsung Remote Test lab (developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action). Crash is reproducible. I do not have a crash log.

Update 2: Seems the problem was elsewhere, I used Fabric to get the crash log and it was the onClick of the button that was not able to identify the target function. Resolved with onClickListener instead. But this is weird, only happened in Samsung devices.

Comment: "Following Android code crashes in Samsung Galaxy with Android 7.0" -- how do you know? If you are getting a stack trace, edit your question and post it.

Comment: I got a message from a user about this. Just now, I tried this with a Samsung Remote Test Lab (developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action) device, it was Galaxy Note with Marshmallow. And the problem was reproducible there.

Comment: "I do not have a crash log" --then you need to arrange to collect stack traces from your app on users' devices. That could be through your distribution channel (e.g., Play Store's developer console) or through a a library (e.g., ACRA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem was elsewhere, I used Fabric to get the crash log and it was the onClick of the button that was not able to identify the target function. Resolved with onClickListener instead. But this is weird, only happened in Samsung devices.